# Trying to check the folders in a particular path are shared or not using powershell. If shared a true value will be returned

Tags: powershell

My script

```
Get-ChildItem "Test path" | ForEach-Object{
$vari = [bool](Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Share -Filter "path = 'test path'")
echo $vari
```

Please help me with the script

Comment: Please add more description in the question, less in the title. What is the issue with the script - "please help me" doesn't give us much to work with.

Comment: Why a foreach if you always filter the base path, or why get-childitem if the check is meant for only ome path.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid querying `wmi` repeatedly, reverse the logic:

```
$TestPath = 'd:\test path'
$AllShares = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Share
Get-ChildItem $TestPath -Directory <#-Recurse<##> -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
    ForEach-Object{
        $vari = $_.FullName -in $AllShares.Path
        if (<#$true -or <##> $vari) { '{0,-6}{1}' -f $vari, $_.FullName }
}
```

Optionally, remove block comment starting tag `<#` (you could retain `<##>` then).