# Get-ChildItem and non-breaking space

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

While working on my file servers, I have noticed one strange folder that broke my script. Folder has name consisting of only one character with ascii value 160 ([non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space), NBSP). Visually that name is the same as space character.

Briefly, I have `Get-ChildItem` being executed on this folder and it is entering endless loop. Command is in reality executed against parent folder and it returns again problematic folder, so my script got into endless loop.

You can easily simulate this on your own environment. In `C:\temp` folder create new folder whose name consists only of NBSP. You can type that with holding alt and pressing 0160 on numerical keyboard. After creating it, run

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Temp\ -Recurse
```

you will get endless list of folders without name, although I have only that one folder.

```
d-----        6/15/2017   2:20 PM
d-----        6/15/2017   2:20 PM
d-----        6/15/2017   2:20 PM
d-----        6/15/2017   2:20 PM
d-----        6/15/2017   2:20 PM
. . .
```

I tested this with PowerShell 4 and 5, on Server and Client OS and its the same behavior. Command `Get-Item` is having also issue with this name, and both switches `-Path` and `-LiteralPath` are behaving in the same way. I tried also `[System.IO.Directory]` class, but it was having the same issue.

**Question:** I have updated my script to report folders with this name as an error and skip it, but I am wondering is there some more smart way to do it? My goal would be to run `Get-ChildItem` or equivalent against such folder.

Is this a known issue? Would be be worth reporting it somewhere as a bug, if confirmed by more people?

Comment: Yep, I see it too. Definitely a bug. `DirectoryInfo` works for me: `([IO.DirectoryInfo]'c:\temp').EnumerateFileSystemInfos('*', 'AllDirectories')`

Comment: I can confirm this too and undoubtly this is somehow exploitable. I would encourage you to report it.

Comment: @wOxxOm can you still recurse into that NBSP folder should it contain another folder? Also, can you literally get dirinfo about the NBSP folder and not just "temp"?

Comment: @Vesper, yes we can! As for the 2nd task, I had to add a slash: `[io.directoryinfo]'R:\1\ \'`

Comment: For c:\temp works with or without final backslash, but for NBSP folder only with it.

Comment: And, yea, good old DIR /S works fine also (not in PoSh console, as there it is just alias to gci)

Comment: Looking at the recursion happening on the stack, I would assume this to be reproducable in any .Net language.

Comment: I have noticed the same behaviour today while answering [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44570716/3439404). The bug appears for **any** folder name which contains `U+00A0` _No-Break Space_ not only for one-character folder name. Moreover, if such a folder contains a _commonly_ named folder, then `dir d:\test -Recurse | % {$_.FullName}` repeats a sequence of child items indefinitely… Finally, it throws `System.InsufficientExecutionStackException` or `CallDepthOverflow` error.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers was right. This is not a PowerShell issue, but a dotnet. I have opened an issue there.
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/21096

Comment: It seems this bug only occurs when the NBSP is the last character in the folder name.  As pointed out by wOxxOm above adding the slash works around it.  Sadly with PS we can only do that to the path input; the function calls .Net code rather that being itself recursive, so creating a proxy function to append that slash gives no joy.

Comment: I'd post your workaround as the answer, and file a bug report. This is surely not the expected behavior for the cmdlet.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://community.idera.com/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/finding-illegal-characters-in-paths-file-system-directory) can help?

Comment: Issue is flagged as closed (as of a couple weeks ago). Not sure how long before it appears in a .NET update for us plebs. My current version of .NET appears to be 4.6.01590. Is this in the latest non-preview version (4.6.2, I think)?

FWIW, my current version of PowerShell is at 5.0.10586.672

Comment: I remember special device names like CON, AUX or PRN used for directories causing problems in Microsoft systems.

Comment: Are you able to use `-Filter '* *'` to target the objects with the offending character and fix them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you found an actual error that will hopefully soon being fixed.

However, there is a very acceptable workaround that you can apply with minimal effort while continuing to use Get-ChildItem without the need to exclude your folder.

The Unicode version of Get-ChildItem does not suffer from this problem. 
(Tested on Powershell 5.1 on a Windows 10 environment)
To use it, simply replace

```
Get-ChildItem  -Path 'c:\__tmp' -recurse
```

by

```
Get-ChildItem  -LiteralPath '\\?\c:\__tmp' -recurse
```

**Additional note**

If you need to deal with UNC, the UNC unicode call is slightly different.

```
Get-ChildItem  -LiteralPath '\\?\UNC\127.0.0.1\c$\__tmp' -recurse
```

Notice that I use for this to work properly the `-LiteralPath` parameter instead of `-Path`.

References

**From Microsoft documentation**

`-LiteralPath`

Specifies a path to one or more locations. Unlike the -Path parameter, the value of the -LiteralPath parameter is used exactly as it is typed. No characters are interpreted as wildcards. If the path includes escape characters, enclose it in single quotation marks. Single quotation marks tell Windows PowerShell not to interpret any characters as escape sequences.

[source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-5.1)

Regarding the unicode prefix convention: [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx?ppud=4)

**Bonus**
The unicode call also have the benefit of solving the 260 characters path length limit : [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46309524/934946)