# How to list files with specific extension with long path name without waiting hours in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I need to list recursively all files in a UNC path with a specific extension (.PST).

I have tried this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "\\DFS.LAN\users\*" -Recurse | ?{$_.Name -like "*.pst"} |
    Select FullName
```

Some errors appears (path too long), how can I deal with it?

```
Get-ChildItem : Impossible de trouver une partie du chemin d'accès
'\\DFS.LAN\users\User1\Documents\...'.
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ Get-ChildItem -Path "\\DFS.LAN\users\*" -Recurse | ?{$_.Name -li ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (\\DFS.LAN\users...:String) [Get-ChildItem], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

**EDIT**

After a little search, it is possible (with PowerShell 5.1) to avoid error with long path name like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "\\?\UNC\DFS.LAN\users\*" -Recurse |
    ?{$_.Name -like "*.pst"} |
    Select FullName
```

> [Explanation Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46308030/handling-path-too-long-exception-with-new-psdrive/46309524)
>
> Example
>
> `Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath '\\?\C:\Very long path' -Recurse`
>
> For UNC path, this is slightly different, the prefix being \?\UNC\
>   instead of \
>
> `Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath '\\?\UNC\127.0.0.1\c$\Very long path\' -Recurse`

Is it possible to inscrease the speed of this listing?

**EDIT**

Maybe using the `-Filter` parameter increase the speed of this task ...

```
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "\\?\UNC\DFS.LAN\users\*" -Filter "*.pst" -Recurse |
    Select FullName
```

Comment: Did your updated command do what you need, or do you still have a question?

Comment: I think you nailed it with your latest edit. Maybe one little thing: you may want to do `Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName` to retrieve the name as string or shorten the code using `(Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "\\?\UNC\DFS.LAN\users\*" -Filter "*.pst" -Recurse).FullName`